# Rewrite Rule for dynamic page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up rewriterule in Wordpress, with a rule.
Whichever user opens: /user/public-profile/something
to execute actually in the backend: /user/public-profile/?n=something

This is my code that does not work for me:

> RewriteRule ^user/public-profile/([^/]*)$ /user/public-profile/?n=$1 [L,NC]

I need idealy solution for wordpress, with add_rewrite_rule. 
But a .htaccess rewriterule will do as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When executing in the backend the other page, I don't want url to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

add_rewrite_rule('user/public-pprofile/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=public-profile&public-profile=$matches[1](http://clivern.com/how-to-add-custom-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress/)', 'top');

obviously substitute your actual slug here for the pagename argument.  [Here's](http://clivern.com/how-to-add-custom-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress/) more detailed explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. And the "detail explanation" as well. 
There is a typo in a public-profile URL.
Can someone propose a CHECKED IN solution that really works.

Comment: Did you try using it as a plugin as described at the bottom of the article? This exact solution works for me with the only difference being that I used different url arguments.